# Oracle Apex Where to run PLSQL code for creating job scheduler because its giving error when executed as a dynamic action

Tags: plsql, jobs, oracle-apex-5

I have written PL SQL code for creating job and trying to execute as dynamic action linked to a button but displays error as

```
  Ajax call returned server error ORA-27452:
```

My Pl SQL Code

```
   Begin

   dbms_scheduler.create_job
   (job_name=> 'myproc',
   job_type=> 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   job_action=> 'CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc IS
   CurrDep Number;
   Tot Number ;
   accm Number;
   Cursor Cur_lcd is
   select  * from Courier_Scanner;
   Cur_row Courier_Scanner%rowtype;
   Begin

   for Cur_row  in Cur_lcd
   Loop
   CurrDep := (Cur_row.PURCHASE_PRICE- Cur_row.SALVAGE)/Cur_row.LIFE_SPAN;
   accm:= Cur_row.TOTAL_ACC_DEP;
   Tot :=   CurrDep + accm;
   Update Courier_Scanner
   set CURR_PRED_DEP =Currdep,
   TOTAL_ACC_DEP=Tot,
   NET_VALUE= Cur_row.PURCHASE_PRICE-Tot, 
   ACCUMULATED_DEP=accm where  SC_NO =Cur_row.SC_NO;
   end loop;

   commit;
   END myproc;  ',
   enabled=>true,
   repeat_interval => 'freq=0; byminute=; bysecond=30;',
   comments=>'depreciation job every year');

   end;
```

This code has been written as dynamic action linked to a button item of static content region of Apex 5.I have searched the error on internet but couldn't find this error

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance

I tried like this before the way Tony is saying. Even that is not working

```
   declare
   My_job  varchar2(255);

   begin
   My_job := dbms_scheduler.generate_job_name('APEXCOMMUNITY_');

   DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name = 'My_job',
   job_type = 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   job_action = 'MYPROC',
   start_date = '10-AUG-17 02.00.00 AM',
   repeat_interval = 'freq=yearly; bymonth=jan; bymonthday=1',
   end_date = '10-AUG-27 02.00.00 AM',
   auto_drop = FALSE,
   comments = 'My new job');
   END;

   EXEC DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE('My_job');



   end;

   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc AS


   CurrDep Number;
   Tot Number ;
   accm Number;
   Cursor Cur_lcd is
   select  * from Courier_Scanner;
   Cur_row Courier_Scanner%rowtype;

   Begin

   for Cur_row  in Cur_lcd
   Loop
   CurrDep := (Cur_row.PURCHASE_PRICE- Cur_row.SALVAGE)/Cur_row.LIFE_SPAN;
   accm:= Cur_row.TOTAL_ACC_DEP;
   Tot :=   CurrDep + accm;
   Update Courier_Scanner
   set CURR_PRED_DEP =Currdep,
   TOTAL_ACC_DEP=Tot,
   NET_VALUE= Cur_row.PURCHASE_PRICE-Tot 
   ACCUMULATED_DEP=accm where  SC_NO =Cur_row.SC_NO;
   end loop;

   End;

   commit;
   END myproc;
```

The above code displays the following error

```
   ORA-06550: line 24, column 4: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"               
   when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare end exception                      
   exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while 
     with <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind 
    variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock insert open 
    rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
```

Comment: I don't understand: you want to create a scheduled job that recreates the same stored procedure every 30 seconds?  Seems very odd.  I imagine you need to use dynamic PL/SQL like `begin execute immediate ''create or replace...end;'' end;`

Comment: Actually i want it to recreate it every year but for checking purpose i have kept 30 secs interval

Comment: OK - but the code will always be the same.  Are you expecting something/someone to have dropped the procedure in between runs?  Normally a stored procedure just sits there forever.

Comment: Sits there forever but runs only once on click event. What i want is that the job starts running on click event and then repeats  the procedure every year

Comment: But your code doesn't **run** the procedure, it creates or replaces it.  To run it the action would be `begin myproc; end;`

Comment: Also, leave APEX and dynamic actions and AJAX out of the equation for now - what happens if you run your code from SQL Plus (or SQL Developer, or Toad...)?

Comment: You mean like this

Comment: i have edited my question to include the code i tried before the way you are talking about "To run it the action would be `begin myproc; end;`"

Comment: You changed the action to `myproc`.  I said change it to `begin myproc; end;`

Comment: Yes i did add it to the code as call to the procedure `begin myproc; end;` but it say myproc is undefined

Comment: Well you probably need to run your `create or replace myproc...` code in SQL Plus or similar first?

Comment: Ohk. I understood now. Thank You Tony for tolerating me